# Highcharts real time chart with incoming Json data [FIXED[]

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, charts, highcharts

Hello I am using multiple  charts from single json data , I am unable to fill highcharts data series with incoming json data . I have used ajax as per highchart manual its of no use  . I need to input first 2 json data to Chart 1 and next 3 data to chart 2 and last data to chart 3 .  Here is my incoming json data .

```
{
    "male": 7,
    "female": 74,
    "loc1": 28,
    "loc2": 3,
    "loc3": 0,
    "count1": 5,
    "count2": 5,
    "count3": 8,
    "temp1": 8,
    "temp2": 22
}
```

Here is my Highcharts  format for Chart 1

```js
<script>
Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
  renderTo : 'chart1',
  backgroundColor: "#000",
        },    
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
     pointPadding: 0.2,
              borderWidth: 0,        
        }
    },
  xAxis: {
        categories: ['Male' ,'Female'],
     labels: {
                style: {
         fontSize: '20px'    
                }
            },
       },
    yAxis: {
           labels: {
                style: {
                 color: 'rgba(255,206,202,0.9)',
        fontSize: '20px'
                }
            },
        min: 0 ,
   title: {
            text: null
        }
    },   
    series: [{
             data: [{y: 2, color: 'rgba(255,90,60,1)'}, {y:5, color: 'rgba(255,170,200,1)'}]
        }
  ]
});  
</script>
```

Thsi ajax code is from Highcharts Demo ,

```js
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.php',
  dataType: 'json',
        success: function(point ) {
    
   chart.series[0].addPoint({color: "#000", name: "Adding A Point",value: "$ 1234.00", y: 1234.00});
    
   

            
            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1*1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
 }
```

In above chart i need to fill Y:2 and Y:5 i.e Male and Female ,  Data value from incoming json data for chart1 i.e first Two Key value pair from json data .

currently this chart 1 is of fixed data. I need to get data updated Dynamically from Json 
I have two others charts as of same format.

any help for making AJAX call to insert data to series.

Any help to load above chart with json data will greatly appreciated.

Thanks:
I have fixed

```js
 <script> 
 var cha1;  
 var cha2;
 var cha3;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jsonlive.php',
  dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){  
   cha1.series[0].setData([{y: data.male, color: 'rgba(202,17,2,0.9)'}, {y:data.female, color: 'rgba(255,206,202,0.9)'} ]);   
   cha2.series[0].setData([data.loc1,data.temp2,data.loc2,data.loc3,data.count1]);
   cha3.series[0].setData([{y:data.count2, color: '#ffcf48'}, {y: data.count3, color: '#fc5656'},{y:data.temp1, color: '#e35fff'}]);
            /*setTimeout(requestData, 1*1000); */   
        },
        cache: false
    })
 };
requestData();                                       // To output when the page loads
setInterval(requestData, (2*1000));
</script>
```

This must be ajax code

Comment: What Ajax code have you tried? What went wrong in this code?

Comment: function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.php',
  dataType: 'json',
        success: function(point ) {
    
   chart.series[0].addPoint({color: "#000", name: "Adding A Point",value: "$ 1234.00", y: 1234.00});
    
   

            
            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1*1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 <script> 
 var cha1;  
 var cha2;
 var cha3;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jsonlive.php',
  dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){  
   cha1.series[0].setData([{y: data.male, color: 'rgba(202,17,2,0.9)'}, {y:data.female, color: 'rgba(255,206,202,0.9)'} ]);   
   cha2.series[0].setData([data.less15,data.sixteen,data.twentysix,data.thirtysix,data.fortysixplus]);
   cha3.series[0].setData([{y:data.happy, color: '#ffcf48'}, {y: data.neutral, color: '#fc5656'},{y:data.surprise, color: '#e35fff'}]);
            /*setTimeout(requestData, 1*1000); */   
        },
        cache: false
    })
 };
requestData();                                       // To output when the page loads
setInterval(requestData, (2*1000));
</script>
```

This above code is used to get json data and send to chart 1 , chart 2 and chart 3 .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    cha1 = new Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
  renderTo : 'chart1',
  backgroundColor: "#636363",
        marginTop: 25,
       },
       
       .......highchart code
       
       and for data put 
       .....
       
       data[]
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950810/highcharts-real-time-chart-with-incoming-json-data-fixed#
```